# Can the Switch button in Shiny to automatically retrieve the available databases?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a Shiny app that reads database files in the data folder. I set up the UI select input to show the names of these folders. However, in the server reactive Switch I need to write down all the data names again (bold section in the code below). Is it possible to make this automatic so I can dump a number of files and the app automatically recognises the files?

Thanks

```
# Load data ----
filenames <- dir("data")
objectnames <- gsub("results", "", filenames)
objectnames <- gsub(".csv", "", objectnames)
for(i in objectnames){
  assign(i, read.csv(paste("data/results_",i,".csv", sep="")))}

# Source helper functions -----
source("plotalot4.R")

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Curve finder"),
  
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
    sidebarPanel("Type your protein",
                 submitButton("Go!"),
               selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                label = "Choose a dataset:",
                choices = objectnames),
      
    mainPanel(h1("Melting curves"), 
             plotOutput("meltingCurve", width = 580, height = 400))
              
  )
)
# Define server logic required to
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           **"bla" = bla,
           "quack" = quack,
           "moo" = moo,
           "neigh" = neigh)**
  })
   
  output$meltingCurve <- renderPlot({
    plotalot4(db=datasetInput(), protein = input$Protein_ID)
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The question is unclear. The `input$dataset` is just a **character vector**. So to get the object you can use `get()`. Then you can just do `datasetInput <- get(input$dataset)`

Comment: Oh, and I meant you can just put `datasetInput <- get(input$dataset)` in renderPlot rather than in a separate reactive expression.